# why input type=date is different width to input type=text?

Tags: html, css

Within the same container input text with display: block stretches to fill available space as expected but if I change type to 'date' it becomes shorter. Why?

HTML:

```
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="text1">text1</label>
      <input id="text1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="date">date</label>
      <input id="date" type="date" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="text2">text2</label>
      <input id="text2" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.panel {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-group {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: left;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
}
```

Result: text1 and text2 are the same size but date is shorter.

https://jsfiddle.net/e0v13ns3/

Comment: what browser? ff is fine

Comment: All `input` fields have some default width that varies from browser to browser. You can add `width: 100%` to fill the available space. There is no problem at all...

Comment: @yellowsir It happens in both Edge and Chrome. Tried in FF and it's not happening there.

Comment: @MaximSuponya Well that demonstrates Mohammad's point perfectly. Browsers have different styles to each other sometimes

Comment: One thing I found to be curious is that if you enable user agent/browser styles in any dev tools panel, neither `input` nor `input[type="date"]` has any default width (or height) value. In fact, Chrome's "computed" styles even link back to the source of the style, but there isn't any for width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `input` of type `text` has a `size` attribute which defaults to 20, and give it an initial width.

An `input` of type `date` doesn't, its width is set using CSS, hence their initial width differs.

*Note, these preset width's can differ between browsers as well.*

Here is a sample where the first `input` has a size of 10

```html
<div>
  <input id="text1" type="text" size="10" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="date" type="date" />
</div>
<div>
  <input id="text2" type="text" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements default width and height may differ from browser to another.

Specify the `height` and `padding` for the `input` element to make them all have the same height, and specify the `width` to make them all have the same width.

Give all the `input` elements a 100% width, and change the `parent div` width depending on your needs.

```css
.panel {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.input-group {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: left;
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}

label, input {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="text1">text1</label>
      <input id="text1" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="date">date</label>
      <input id="date" type="date" />
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
      <label for="text2">text2</label>
      <input id="text2" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Let's see. Does this question answer `...if I change type to 'date' it becomes shorter. Why?` No, no it doesn't. This is a *solution*, not an explanation to the question.

Comment: @ProEvilz, indeed. I suspect there may be some reasoning behind and I want to know what it is.